# Minor revised article will take how long time for final verdict?

Tags: journal-workflow

I submitted an article in June end and it came for minor revision on Sep first week. Then I submitted the revised manuscript within 10 days. After that, it took 2 and half months for getting reviewer scores, 3 weeks to get recommendation and now it is almost 2 weeks. Still the status is awaiting decision. Still how long will it take for the final verdict?
Thank you

Comment: Depends upon your specific editor and journal.

Answer (score 1):

The reviewers and editors are people just like you and me. Today is the 3rd of January, thus, I would assume that they might still be on christmas vacation. In my personal experience, people often leave early for christmas, like in mid December. Some will return to work in the second week of January, so they might still be out of office.

Therefore I am not really surprised that you are waiting for almost two weeks now. Just give it some more time.

Comment: +1, since if I read the question right, the paper is waiting for the editors to make a decision, in which case your answer is the most likely scenario.